# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': I want to fixe

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hello I have this problem and and i don't know what to do
I created a new Project with STS, Maven and hibernate,Struts2 and tried to 
include Spring Security. Since then i get the following error. Has anyone got an idea what went wrong?!

Error

```
GRAVE: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'utilisateurService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'utilisateurService' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
  <display-name>ExempleContext</display-name>
  <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
  <listener>
enter code here    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/security.xml
     </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

security.xml

```
 [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">
        <http>

            <access-denied-handler error-page="/private/accessDenied.jsp" />


            <!-- isAnonymous() or hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS') -->
            <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/img/**" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/logout*" access="isAuthenticated()" />





            <!-- permettre l'acces aux actions public -->
            <intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="isAnonymous()" />

            <!-- zone privée user -->
            <intercept-url pattern="/private/user/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/private/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

            <!-- zone privée admin -->

            <intercept-url pattern="/private/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/private/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/private/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />

            <form-login login-page="/public/showLoginPage"
                default-target-url="/private/initUserHome"
                authentication-failure-url="/public/loginFailure.jsp" />

            <logout logout-success-url="/public/showLoginPage" logout-url="/logout"
                delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />

        </http>

        <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="utilisateurService">
                <password-encoder hash="sha">
                    <salt-source user-property="username" />
                </password-encoder>

            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>

        <!-- <authentication-manager> -->
        <!-- <authentication-provider> -->
        <!-- <user-service> -->
        <!-- <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" /> -->
        <!-- <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" /> -->
        <!-- </user-service> -->
        <!-- </authentication-provider> -->
        <!-- </authentication-manager> -->
    </beans:beans>][2]

pomme.xml




    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.ensah</groupId>
        <artifactId>e_service</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <properties>
            <struts2.version>2.3.16.3</struts2.version>
            <struts2-jquery.version>4.0.2</struts2-jquery.version>
            <spring.security.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
            <spring.version> 4.3.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <hibernate.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate.version>
            <sl4j.version>1.7.2</sl4j.version>
            <mysql.connector.java.version>5.1.25</mysql.connector.java.version>
        </properties>



        <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
            <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Struts 2 + Spring 3 need this jar, ContextLoaderListener -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Spring security -->

             <!-- <dependency> 
             <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
             <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId> 
             <version>${spring.security.version}</version> 
             </dependency>  -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- <dependency> -->
            <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> -->
            <!-- <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId> -->
            <!-- <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version> -->
            <!-- </dependency> -->

            <!-- Struts 2 + Spring integration plugins -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Hibernate -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <version>3.17.1-GA</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>${mysql.connector.java.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
                <version>${struts2.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${struts2.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${struts2.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${struts2.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
                <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${struts2-jquery.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.11</version>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>
        <!-- Décommenter ça pour les versions récentes de Spring Security qui n'existent 
            pas encore dans le repository Maven -->
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <build>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your stack trace - spring could not find bean with name `utilisateurService` in `UserDetailsService`. Just define this bean via XML configuration or with annotation `@Service` if you are using annotation based configuration.

Comment: Sorry i have question, Will I add UtilisateurService in applicationContext.xml or security.xml ?

Comment: You can define it in applicationContext.xml.